# Visual Studio: How to change target framework used by editor?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I have a multi-platform solution with many `csproj` files configured this way:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>net452;netstandard1.4</TargetFrameworks>    
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.4' ">    
  <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.0"/>
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452' ">
  <Reference Include="System.Net" />
  <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="6.0.8" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that I don't have a `TargetFramework` element (the singular form). I only have the `TargetFrameworks` element (the plural form).

The editor assumes `netstandard1.4` and all `#if NET452` blocks get grayed out and without IntelliSense.

How can I tell Visual Studio editor to recognize a specific target framework (`net452`, `netstandard1.4`), and get IntelliSense, at least temporarily?

For reference, I'm using VS2017 Professional version 15.2 (26430.16).

Comment: you don't have TargetFramework element? But what is it? <TargetFrameworks>net452;netstandard1.4</TargetFrameworks>

Comment: That's the plural form. I don't have the singular form.

it looks like the editor is always choosing .netstandard1.4. All blocks #if NET452 are grayed out and there is not intellisense.

Comment: The entire point of a .NETStandard is to never have to do this.  So the only logical thing to do is to not do it, doing it anyway is something you'll regret sooner or later.  Well, sooner.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there some hack I can use while we don't get quite there? For instance, define some environment variable such as NET452? Or perhaps change some configuration?

Answer (score 6):

Here's the answer:

- Visual Studio 2017 contains 3 combo-boxes on top of the editor. On version 15.1 or above, the leftmost combo allows selecting the framework for editing. That will change syntax highlight of `#if` blocks according to the selected framework.
- IntelliSense seems to cover all items declared on `TargetFrameworks`, even if the text is grayed at editor.

All in all, it was just my learning curve.

Comment: Does anyone know which setting toggles those combo boxes on/off? Cause I don't have them even in VS 2022.

Comment: Update: It's TOOLS -> Text Editor -> C# -> General -> Navigation bar